# .htaccess redirect to a new domain WITHOUT reload the page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, reverse-proxy

Currently, I'm making a website and I would like this site to redirect (via `.htaccess`) to another domain WITHOUT reloading the page. Because in all the tutorials I saw, it loaded the page of the new domain. Outside what I want is that it keeps the page of the base domain while displaying the URL of the new domain.

**Example:**

redirect this site

```
https://DOMAIN1.US/folder1/folder2/page.html?param=1&param=2
```

to this site

```
https://DOMAIN2.US/folder1/folder2/page.html?param=1&param=2
```

Comment: Do you have access to the main server config of domain1? "all the tutorials I saw, it loaded the page of the new domain" - probably because what you are after is not a "redirect". You need to configure the source server (ie. `domain1`) as a "reverse proxy" - this will generally require access to the server config.

Comment: No, i dont have the access to the main server config. Htaccess cannot "fake redirect" @MrWhite ??

Comment: Well, if the server already has the necessary modules installed/enabled then you _might_ be able to simply use the `P` flag with a mod_rewrite directive in `.htaccess` as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> i dont have the access to the main server config. Htaccess cannot "fake redirect" ??

What you are asking for is not a simple "redirect" (which is managed by the browser). You need to configure the server that hosts `domain1.com` as a "reverse proxy" - since this needs to be managed entirely server-side.

The user sends a request to `domain1.com`. The server at `domain1.com` then constructs an internal HTTP request (reverse proxy) to `domain2.com`. The response from `domain2.com` is then sent back to the server at `domain1.com` which then forwards the (possibly "rewritten") response back to the client.

This requires additional modules enabled on the server at `domain1.com`, ie. mod_proxy, mod_proxy_http and additional (optional) modules such as mod_proxy_html, etc. depending on your requirements.

Ideally, you would then configure this in the server config (or VirtualHost container). Notably, you would need to set `ProxyPassReverse` (in the server config) to cover the scenario of `domain2.com` issuing an external redirect to itself. The proxy server needs to rewrite the response headers so that the redirect goes to `domain1.com`, not `domain2.com`. `ProxyPassReverse` cannot be set in `.htaccess`.

You can then use mod_rewrite with mod_proxy by using the `P` flag. This part you can do in `.htaccess`. For example, to proxy the request from `https://DOMAIN1.US/folder1/folder2/page.html?param=1&param=2` to `https://DOMAIN2.US/folder1/folder2/page.html?param=1&param=2`.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.us [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain2.us%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

If you have access to the server config then you can do this more simply with the `ProxyPass` directive (no need for mod_rewrite in this instance since the source and target URLs are the same).

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html